# Command Line interface issue in Orchard | feature enable command not recognized

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7, orchard-modules

I am using Orchard CMS 1.7.3

When enabling the Orchard.CodeGeneration feature through command line, below error is thrown always: 
[image]

I followed the steps here : http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Command-line-scaffolding

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you started the application at least once? Cooked a recipe?

Comment: Ok. Is it necessary to setup the website once / Cook a Recipe ?

Comment: Features can only be enabled when there is an actual initialized instance of the Orchard application

Comment: Ok . building and setting up now sir !  Will update shortly

Comment: Thank you devqon. It worked this time. PLease post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Features can only be enabled when the Orchard application is initialized, e.g. cooked a recipe and is setup to be used. This is because enabled features are tracked in the database, which isn't there yet when the application isn't initialized.

Therefore you must first fire up the application at least once and fill in the settings. After that you can use the commands like 'feature enable'.